# Bootstrap multiple applications in Windows

Tags: java, windows, executable-jar

I'm trying to develop a basic application for my dad's office and the OS they run is Windows 8.

I'm trying to develop the application using JFrames for GUI and MySQL for backend.

I will be packaging the entire application as a fat jar and will be deploying in windows.

The problem is,
Every time someone wants to run the application, they have to run the jar specifically and run the mySQL separately (such that it can accept connections). Because every day the windows system will be booted and shutdown at night.

Is there any simpler way to bootstrap everything in a single click?

Comment: Do you want _MySQL_ database to start up automatically when the Windows machine is booted?

Comment: Perhaps you want [Windows batch file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file) ?

Comment: In more of a generalised speaking way, I'm talking about desktop applications.

Comment: Like when an executable application is started in windows, all it's dependencies are startup.

Comment: A [Windows] batch file can run multiple commands. You can create a desktop shortcut. Double clicking the shortcut icon will run the batch file. First command in batch file will start up MySQL and second command will execute `java -jar ...` command.